# Elasticsearch (2.3.4), ignores not_analyzed even though inserted during index creation

Tags: elasticsearch

I created a new index along with the following mapping that turns off analysis.

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/vacation/ -d 
     '{ "mappings": 
          { "rentals": 
               { "properties": 
                     { "name": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" }} 
               }
          }
       }'
```

This request is acknowledged and I inserted a new document called in the index:

```
  { "name": "fire house" }
```

Since analysis is turned off, the document name, "fire house", shouldn't be tokenized. So unless the query is exactly "fire house," the document shouldn't be retrieved. However, the document is being retrieved even though the query term is just "fire" or "house." Could this be an issue with the current version of E.S. I'm using or is it the way I specified mapping during index creation?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you specify any custom analyzer while indexing the document ? 
Would you be able to provide the output of  GET /vacation/rentals/_validate/query?explain

Comment: And what's your query?

Comment: Did you add the document with the 'rentals' type?

Comment: @JVXR, I didn't specify any custom analyzer. Here's the output to the get request: {
  "valid": true,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "explanations": [
    {
      "index": "vacation",
      "valid": true,
      "explanation": "ConstantScore(ConstantScore(+ConstantScore(_type:rentals)))"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: @AndreiStefan, here's the query: curl http://localhost:9200/vacation/_search -d '{ 
 "query": {
  "query_string": {
   "query": "fire"
  }
 }
}'

Comment: @Alain Collins, yes, I posted a document using this: curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/vacation/rentals -d '{ "name": "fire house" }'

Comment: Pull the index mapping with curl and make sure it was applied as you wanted.

Comment: By default, the ES engine does a full text "match" search, If you want an "exact" search you will have better luck using a term query query:{ {
    "term" : { "name" : "fire" } 
}}

Comment: @AlainCollins, I checked the mapping it, not_analyzed is set for the name field, and there's not other field in a document indexed.

Comment: @JVXR, I've tried that query, and it doesn't work either :/

Comment: @JVXR, strangely enough, I tried the query with the field specified, and it worked finally.